# Properties of the maximum of a multivariate Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $g:[0,1] \times [0,1 ] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $K$-Lipschitz function (w.r.t. the $\ell_1$-norm). Consider the maximal function $$f(x) = \arg \max_{y\in [0,1]} g(x, y).$$

I'm interested in what can be inferred about the function $f$. In particular, is the function $f$ itself $K$-Lipschitz? If not, is there a way to bound the difference $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$? (Does $f$ have any other interesting properties?)

Edit: As @madnessweassley pointed out, in general $f$ is not Lipschitz. As a result, I'm wondering whether assumptions such as monotonicity of the max help: Assume $g$ satisfies that if $x \geq x'$, then $$\max_{y\in [0,1]} g(x, y) \geq \max_{y\in [0,1]} g(x', y).$$

**Edit 2:** After some thought, the question now is more generally:
*What conditions must we impose on $g$ so that $f$ is also $K$-Lipschitz (or Lipschitz w.r.t. a slightly different constant)?*

Comment: Did you mean to define $f(x) = \max_{y \in [0,1]} g(x,y)$? If yes, we can write $\lvert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \rvert = \lvert \max_{y \in [0,1]} g(x_1,y) - \max_{y \in [0,1]} g(x_2,y) \rvert \leq \max_{y \in [0,1]} \lvert g(x_1,y) - g(x_2,y) \rvert \leq \max_{y \in [0,1]} K \lVert x_1 - x_2 \rVert_1  = K \lVert x_1 - x_2 \rVert_1$.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, I really meant the $\arg \max$ (and not the $\max$).

Comment: I don't think you can expect $f$ to be Lipschitz in that case. A simple counterexample: $g(x,y) = (x-0.5)y$. Then we have $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if } 0 \leq x < 0.5 \\
[0,1], & \text{if } x = 0.5 \\
1, & \text{if } 0.5 < x \leq 1
\end{cases}$. Note that in general, $f$ is a set-valued mapping. You could expect $f$ to be locally Lipschitz under some rather strict conditions, e.g., [see Chapter 6.3 of this book](https://optimization-online.org/2018/04/6587/)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting counterexample. Please also see my edit, if you have a guess whether such monotonicity assumption is enough for Lipschitzness or other ways to bound $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$.

Comment: I think my counterexample satisfies your monotonicity property...

Comment: You're right... I looked at it and for some reason thought it didn't satsify the condition.

Comment: If the minimum of $f(x_0,\cdot)$ is achieved in only one point $y_0$, you can prove that $f(x) \to y_0$ when $x \to x_0$ whatever you choose for $f(x)$ when the maximum is multiply achieved. To get more regularity you need bounds on how $f(x_0,y)$ decreases when $y$ leaves $y_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, Theorem 6.2 of [these notes](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf) state sufficient conditions under which $f$ is locally Lipschitz at $\bar{x} \in (0,1)$ in a suitable sense. I'm reproducing the result below.

> Theorem 6.2 of [Still](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf): Suppose $g$ is twice continuously differentiable and $\bar{y}$ is a strict local maximizer of $\max_{y \in [0,1]} g(\bar{x},y)$ of order two. Then, there are constants $\varepsilon, \delta, L > 0$ such that for all $x \in B_{\varepsilon}(\bar{x})$, there exists a local maximizer $y(x)$ of $\max_{y \in [0,1]} g(x,y)$ satisfying $\lVert y(x) - \bar{y} \rVert \leq L \lVert x - \bar{x} \rVert$ (i.e., $f$ is locally Lipschitz at $\bar{x}$ with local Lipschitz constant $L$ in an appropriate sense).

Definition 2.1 of [Still](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/6587.pdf) defines what is a strict local maximizer of order two, and Theorem 2.4 therein identifies sufficient conditions for a local maximizer to be a strict local maximizer of order two.